# Radius of convergence of following power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The following was a quiz question in real analysis whose answer is different than what I marked . I am asking for explanation here.

> Consider the power series $\sum_{n\geq1}a_n z^n $ where $a_n $= number of divisors of of $n^{50}$ . Then the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n\geq1} a_n z^n $ is ?

1/R =n th root of $a_n$ as n tends to $\infty$ <$  n^{50/n}$ as n tends to $\infty$ =1.

But answer is 0, which can happen as there is inequality in my deduction. But I don't know how to prove that ROC is 0.

Kindly shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I can give you a **blind guess** that may be worthless: (1) I suspect that the ROC of the alternative $\sum_{n\geq 1} nz^n$ is 0. (2) I suspect that number of divisors of $n$ increases approximately in the same way as $n$ increases.  Even if my **suspicions** are **totally wrong**, it may be sufficient to drive the ROC $\to 0$ if (as $n \to \infty$) it *occasionally* has a large (i.e. unbounded) # of divisors.  Obviously, I am only giving you blind instinct, so take this with **a large grain of salt.**

Comment: @user2661923 . You are right, by the Hadamard-Cauchy Radius Formula.

Comment: I don't think the ROC is $0$ because number of divisors is indeed bound by $n^{50}$ and $\lim n^{1/n} = 1$, so $\lim n^{50/n} = 1$, so the radius of convergence is at least $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n}=1.\;$ So $\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{50/n}=(\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{1/n})^{50}=1.$

$\lim\sup_{n\to  \infty}|a_n|^{1/n} \le \lim\sup_{n\to \infty}n^{50/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}n^{50/n}=1.$

So the ROC is at least $1$ by the Hadamard-Cauchy Radius Formula.

If $|z|\ge 1$ then $|a_nz^n|\ge |z^n|\ge 1$ so the sequence of terms of the series does not $\to 0$ so the series does not converge.

So the ROC is at most $1.$